# Jquery Validator valid() function not working on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

We have multiple forms within a single page application. Individual forms have their individual save button on which individual form gets validated and if valid (using jquery validator .valid() method) then record gets saved in Database which is working fine.

Problem we are facing here is that when in the last form which is the final submit, when we try to validate all other forms for its validation using .valid() method, it always returns true irrespective of the wrong validations.

```
$("#submitForm").submit(function(event) {
     $("#educationForm").validate();
     console.log($("#educationForm").valid());

});
```

Here console also gives true even if the education Form is invalid

Kindly help us with this issue.

Regards,
Suvojit

Comment: You should use `event.preventDefault()` to stop form from submitting

Comment: Thats fyn.. I have included that in my code....Its not about form submission but I am getting true even if the education Form is not validated.

Comment: well you can not have forms in forms so not sure how that code is supposed to work... Maybe a basic example that shows how it is being used.

Comment: No we are having multiple forms not nested kind off..

Comment: You are incorrectly calling `.validate()` from within a `.submit()` handler.  `.validate()` is only how you'd INITIALIZE the plugin.

Comment: The `.valid()` method was designed to programmatically trigger a validation test. When you click "submit", the plugin is already doing a validation test automatically so there's no point in calling `.valid()` on the "submit" event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> valid() function not working on submit

The `.valid()` method was designed to programmatically trigger a validation test.  When you click "submit", the plugin is automatically doing a validation test, so there's no point in also calling `.valid()` on the "submit" event.

---

I think you may be misunderstanding [the basic usage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)...

```
$("#submitForm").submit(function(event) {
     $("#educationForm").validate();            // <- INITIALIZES PLUGIN
     console.log($("#educationForm").valid());  // <- TEST VALIDATION
});
```

- You would **never** put `.validate()` inside of an event handler other than a DOM ready handler.  **The `.validate()` method is how the plugin is initialized**.
- After it's initialized properly, the plugin *automatically* captures the click event of the submit button.

By putting it inside of a `.submit()` handler, you're interfering with the plugin, which is already trying to capture the exact same event.

Put inside of the DOM ready event handler instead...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#educationForm").validate();            // <- INITIALIZES PLUGIN

     console.log($("#educationForm").valid());  // <- TEST VALIDATION

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2vugwyfe/**

OR:  http://jsfiddle.net/2vugwyfe/1/

---

The validation test is automatically triggered by any `type="submit"` element.

If you need to trigger a validation test by clicking another type of element, then use a custom `.click()` handler...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#educationForm").validate();            // <- INITIALIZES PLUGIN

     $("#button").on('click', function() {
         $("#educationForm").valid();  // <- TEST VALIDATION
     });

});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/pdhvtpdq/**

---

**EDIT**:

To check if a different form is valid, use the `.valid()` method inside of the `submitHandler` option.

In this example, when the `submitHandler` for "Form A" fires, it then checks if "Form B" is valid before allowing a submission.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#form_A").validate({              // initialize plugin on Form A
         submitHandler: function(form) {  // fires when Form A is valid
             if($("#form_B").valid()) {   // tests if Form B is valid
                 $(form).submit();        // submit Form A
             }
         }
     });

});
```

Comment: Hey Sparky,  I had already initiliazed .validate() for all the forms in the DOM ready element, but still .valid() is returning true for other forms on click of final submit button

Comment: @Suvojit, if you already called `.validate()` within the DOM ready handler, then why are you again putting it inside a `submit()` handler?   Please carefully read my answer again and examine the jsFiddle demos.  **You should NOT be using `.valid()` within a submit handler.**  No part of this should require a `.submit()` handler.  Only in the case where you don't have a `type="submit"` button, then you'd need a `click` handler.

Comment: Actually I wanted to check weather all other forms are valid before actually submitting the complete application data ... Is there any way if not .valid() check I can check the same before submitting the form ??

Comment: @Suvojit, yes, you can attach `.valid()` to any form, but you'd put that inside the `submitHandler` option of the plugin, never inside your own `.submit()` handler.  See my edited answer.

Comment: I figured out why my .valid() was not working... It was because i had kept some sections to hidden within the page using css display:none. Whenever I removed this css .valid() method returned false for other forms..May I know that while keeping these other forms hidden how can I make work/validate these forms using same .valid() method??

Comment: @Suvojit, it has nothing to do with the `.valid()` method.  **By default**, the jQuery Validate plugin will **ignore** all hidden form elements, so if the entire form is hidden, then `.valid()` will always be `true`.  If you want to ignore nothing and validate all hidden elements, then you need to set the `ignore` option to `[]`.

Comment: Thanks Sparky... That made my day...:)

Comment: thank dude @Sparky,, your first line really save my head from blasting..i have wasted my 3 hour to know about there is no need to call valid() method in the submit callback to check whether form is fullfilling conditions..really less knowledge is dangerous ..hahahah